# How to fix exterior metal French door with concealed hinges?

Tags: doors, hinges

Just moved in and have a couple of exterior French doors that get stuck. Hinges seem a bit tight and door seems misaligned. Bottom part is the one that touches together.

I don't know what these type of hinges are called so please see attached pictures.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't see any mechanism for adjustment, which is usually present in such door sets. That leaves you with little recourse unless you can find where the jambs attach to the framing. Is that accessible at all?

Comment: Is there a gap where the bottom rail meets the hinge stile? (In other words, is the whole door coming apart?)

Comment: Yeah, some kind of "prehung" door, perhaps.  Can you remove the jamb (well, the whole door) and shave down some of the king stud, or whatever the jamb is screwed to?